# Will lock picking a door in plain sight affect relations with a town or npc

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was wondering can you lock pick a door while other people are around without this affecting your relationship with the town or people adversely. I noticed that if you want to steal something the item is labeled red STEAL but the locked door does not have any such designation. I would like to know if I should be doing this on the sly and not in the open. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with lock picking a door is not that people around it will notice, but that the people inside the building will do. They will awake and start to scream for the guards, possible running outside to fetch one for them. Without having stolen anything a bounty was put on my head...

I haven't seen an empty building so far, but I would guess that the guards will still come for you.

When doing any of these things I would really suggest you to do it in the sly.

Comment: Does someone have to be just inside the building to notice, or within range of the door to see you coming in?

Comment: @DoozerBlake: Most house are small enough for them to hear your footsteps. If not, I guess they will trigger once you come near them as they know that the door was locked...

Comment: There is a perk to silently pick locks.

Comment: Faendal's house in Riverwood. The place was empty when I entered.